# Excel Max in column with header

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2003

How can I get the max value in column without include header (because it's text). 
I need a formula not VBA script.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I don't know the number of rows. The formula needs to work without starts or ends columns.

Comment: Why including header in formula doesn't suit? `max` doesn't take into account text values

Comment: Example - maximum value of cells 12-16 in column E: `=MAX(E12:E16)`.

Comment: Yes, I want this but if I use MAX(A:A) it doesn't work. I get #NAME? error and I think because I have numer + text in same column.

Comment: What language is installed in your office? Seems like you have non - English default language and `max` should have another local name

Comment: Yes, I'm not english. I'm italian so I have installed italian language. But MAX is the right function, it works for =MAX(A1:A10)

Comment: check whether you have `#Name` error in cells below `A10`. This may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the maximum value from cell *A1* to cell *A10*, you can type:

```
=MAX(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10)
```

or:

```
=MAX(A1:A10)
```

If you don't know the start row number and the end row number, simply use all the whole interval (I think Excel has a maximum of 16,384 columns: [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmworksheetworkbook)):

```
=MAX(A1:A16384)
```

Here's an example that show you how text is ignored (in this example I used column 100 as the maximum column length):

[image: Get the maximum value in a column]

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in A1-A4

```
=MAX(OFFSET(A1,1,0,COUNT(A1:A4)-1))
```

Edit: Without a start row you can use A:A, this will ignore text values.

```
=MAX(A:A)
```

if you want to ignore hidden data and errors you can use

```
=AGGREGATE(4,7,A:A)
```

Comment: Why complicate things so much? `=MAX(A1:A4)` is the way